How to find all local minima in a range for a complicated function quickly?
I define a function
 a = 1
 h = 1.1
 b = 1
 g = 1
 t1r = 0
 t2r = 0
 t3r = 0
 t4r = 0
 k1 = 0.3
 k2 = 0.1
 k3 = 1.0
 k4 = 0.8

 A1[theta1_] := 2*a*b*Cos[theta1] - 2*g*b
 B1[theta1_] := 2*a*b*Sin[theta1]
 C1[theta1_] := g^2 + b^2 + a^2 - h^2 - 2*a*g*Cos[theta1]

 theta21[theta1_] :=ArcTan[B1[theta1]/A1[theta1]] - Pi +ArcCos[C1[theta1]/Sqrt[A1[theta1]^2 + B1[theta1]^2]] 
 theta22[theta1_] := ArcTan[B1[theta1]/A1[theta1]] + Pi - ArcCos[C1[theta1]/Sqrt[A1[theta1]^2 + B1[theta1]^2]]
 theta3[theta1_] := ArcSin[(b*Sin[theta22[theta1]] - a*Sin[theta1])/h] - theta1 + Pi
 theta4[theta1_] := 2 Pi - theta1 - (Pi - theta22[theta1]) - theta3[theta1]

 theta1min = ArcCos[((g^2 + a^2) - (h - b)^2)/2 a*g]
 theta2max = ArcCos[((h - a)^2 - (g^2 + b^2))/2 b*g]
 mtheta1 = Re[theta1 /. FindRoot[theta22[theta1] == theta2max, {theta1, theta1min}]]

 energy[theta1_] := 1/2*(k1*Power[(theta1 - t1r), 2] + k2*Power[(Pi - theta22[theta1] - t2r), 2] + k3*Power[(theta3[theta1] - t3r), 2] + k4*Power[(theta4[theta1] - t4r), 2])
 
 Plot[energy[theta1], {theta1, theta1min, mtheta1}]


I want to find all local minima of function energy in the range {theta1min,mtheta1}
I used many ways like solve[D[energy]==0] Localminima[energy]and so on, but the program has been running for a long time without outputting results. I think this is because my function it too complicated.
Although i have seen the question

How to find all the local minima/maxima in a range

i found the methods I mentioned are used in the answers to the above questions.
So I would like to ask if there is any quick way? Thank you so much.

"i found the methods I mentioned" -- Do you mean the solutions in the linked Q&A? You haven't any methods AFAICT.

Semicolons at the ends of lines would suppress needlessly irritating output.

Given my answer, it's unclear what this means: "the program has been running for a long time...." What is the code that has been running so long?

I have no problem with the NDSolve method in the linked Q&A:
Reap[
  NDSolve[{y''[t] == energy''[t], {y'[mtheta1] == energy'[mtheta1], 
     y[mtheta1] == energy[mtheta1]},
    WhenEvent[y'[t] < 0,
     Sow[FindRoot[energy'[theta], {theta, t}], "min"]; {}]}
   , y, {t, theta1min, mtheta1}],
  "min"] // AbsoluteTiming


NDSolve::ndsz: At t == 0.10004171362313169`, step size is effectively zero; singularity or stiff system suspected.
(*
{0.020291,  <-- quite fast
 {{{y -> InterpolatingFunction[{{0.100042`, 4.66237}}, <<>>]}},
  {{{theta -> 4.28283}, {theta -> 1.59422}}}}
 }
*)



This takes less than half a second. Not as fast, but not slow:
NSolve[energy'[t] == 0 && theta1min < t < mtheta1, t]
Select[%, energy''[t] > 0 /. # &]


(*
{{t -> 0.304137}, {t -> 1.59422}, {t -> 3.54557}, {t -> 4.28283}}
{{t -> 1.59422}, {t -> 4.28283}}
*)



Unfortunately, t -> 0.304137} is not a local minimum as the plot shows.

@user64494 Again, you're being careless. The second line (Select[..]) selects the minima from the critical points.

The steps can be combined in NSolve[energy'[t] == 0 && theta1min < t < mtheta1 && energy''[t] > 0, t] but it takes 17+ sec. It often pays to solve systems in smaller steps.

Yes, the united outputs of two different commands misled me.

@user64494 Sorry about that. I guess I could've suppressed the output of NSolve[]. I thought showing both better illustrated the effects of the two steps.

Your approach is totally valid, thank you guys, as I am not a native English speaker so I may have some problems with the presentation and I'm still a mathematica beginner so there's still a long way to go

The solution is the same as the second suggestion by Michel E2, first calculate critical points f'[x] = 0 and determine whether the points are minimal points f''[x] > 0.
p = Plot[energy[theta1], {theta1, theta1min, mtheta1}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {energy'[#] &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize@Medium}]

AbsoluteTiming[
 pts = Cases[p, Point[{x_, y_}] -> {x, y}, ∞] // Sort;
 Cases[Thread@{Sign[energy''[#[[1]]] & /@ pts], pts}, {1, _}][[All,2]]]
{0.0134667, {{1.59422, 2.60626}, {4.28283, 4.13329}}}

This solution is also very fast and you can see what you calculate!
Expansion due to objection from Sigis K.
Strange, I have no problems with version 14.1. Change the procedure as follows:
p = Plot[energy[theta1], {theta1, theta1min, mtheta1}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {energy'[#] &}, MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize@Medium}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 pts = Cases[Normal@p, Point[pt_] :> pt, \[Infinity]] // DeleteDuplicates // SortBy[#, First] &;
 signPts = Thread@{Sign[energy''[#] &@pts[[All, 1]]], pts};
 minima = {#2, {x -> #}} & @@@ Cases[signPts, {1, _}][[All, 2]]]

{0.0154283, {{2.60626, {x -> 1.59422}}, {4.13329, {x -> 4.28283}}}}

Furthermore, you can insert RegionFunction into the Plot
p = Plot[energy[theta1], {theta1, theta1min, mtheta1}, Mesh -> {{0}}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {energy'[#] &}, 
   RegionFunction -> Function[x, energy''[x] > 0], 
   MeshStyle -> {Red, PointSize@Medium}];

AbsoluteTiming[
 minima = MapApply[{#2, {x -> #}} &, 
   Cases[Normal@p, Point[pt_] :> pt, \[Infinity]] // DeleteDuplicates // SortBy[#, First] &]]

{0.0003028, {{2.60626, {x -> 1.59422}}, {4.13329, {x -> 4.28283}}}}

Finally, FindMinimum can be used. Read the approximate minima from the plot and use these as starting points for FindMinima.
startPts = {1.6, 4.2}; (* from the Plot *)
AbsoluteTiming[
 FindMinimum[energy[x], {x, #}, AccuracyGoal -> 5] & /@ startPts]

{0.0055153, {{2.60626, {x -> 1.59422}}, {4.13329, {x -> 4.28283}}}}


If I end your definition of p with  ;   your code will not return any result. Can you explain me why in this case the pattern Point[{x_, y_}] is not found anymore in p ?

I have no problems with version 14.1. I have expanded my answer and changed the procedures a little so that older versions (hopefully) also produce correct results.

Yes when I modify the code {Point[{x_, y_}] -> {x, y} to Point[pt_] :> pt as suggested  your code works with my old version (11.3) of MMA. With that version I find  Point[List[709, 710, 711, 712]] in the Fullform of p  which which  cannot be caught with your first answer. Thanks for your answer

Using FindMinimum:
mins = FindMinimum[{energy[x], theta1min <= x <= mtheta1}, {x, #}] & /@
Round[({theta1min, mtheta1} + 1/2)]


{{2.60626, {x -> 1.59422}}, {4.13329, {x -> 4.28283}}}

Plot[energy[x], {x, theta1min, mtheta1}, 
Epilog -> {Red, AbsolutePointSize[5], Point[mins /. {a_, {c_ -> b_}} :> {b, a}]}]


